# convert specific columns in dataframe to dictionary/list in R

Tags: r, list, dictionary

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
a <- c('zz','yy','xx','qq','pp')
b <- c('1','2','2','3','1')
ab <- data.frame(a,b)
```

This gives:

```
   a b
1 zz 1
2 yy 2
3 xx 2
4 qq 3
5 pp 1
```

I would like to turn this into a dictionary/nested list in R. I can imagine in python, the result would look like this:

```
ab_dict = {'1':["zz","pp"],'2':["yy","xx"],'3':["qq]}
```

How can this be achieved in R? I would like the result to be iterable in a for loop afterwards.

I couldn't find any solution for this on stackoverflow so I apologise if something similar has been asked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to `split` the 'ab' column by 'b' and use `toJSON` from `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(split(as.character(ab$a), ab$b))
#{"1":["zz","pp"],"2":["yy","xx"],"3":["qq"]}
```

Comment: Thank you! I never knew about split! I would however, not convert it into a JSON object because I would like to iterate through the results. Thank you so much!